# Insert a node at specific position in a linked list in C (only)

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong please !!!, I'm a beginner to programming, I'm new to DSA, I'm not able to find my mistake, here is the code please go through it:

> This is the outline of my question, hope it is clear! :)

```
sample input : 3 16 13 7 1 2
3 is the number of elements to input into a linked list
so 16 13 7 are elements of the linked list initially
1 is the element I'm interested to insert
2 is the position where I want to insert the element 1
so the expected output will be:
sample output: 16 13 1 7
```

> The problem I'm facing :

```
The output I'm getting is: 13 1 7
So the problem is not every element in the list is getting returned, please help !!!
```

> This is the code I tried, any suggestions are encouraged, :)

```
   struct SinglyLinkedListNode 
  {
        int data;
        SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
  };

    SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data, int position) 
{
    int i = 0;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *pcurr, *pnew;

    pnew = (SinglyLinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    if(position == 0)
    {
        pnew->data = data;
        pnew->next = head->next;
        head = pnew;
        return head;
    }
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        pnew ->data = data;
        return pnew;
    }
    else
    {
        do 
        {
            pcurr = head;
            pcurr = pcurr->next;
            head = head->next;
            i++;
        }
        while (i != position-1);
        pnew->next = pcurr->next;
        pnew->data = data;
        pcurr->next = pnew;
        return head;
    }
}
```

I would be glad if anyone suggests a good visualising platform for viewing our code line by line especially for c , just like in python.

Comment: What is SinglyLinkedListNode?

Comment: "visualising platform" how about your ide? Or do you mean a debugger? (c)GDB then. Also how are we supposed to help you if you don't provide us with what's going wrong and what is expected

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it should be Struct SinglyLinkedListNode, it is basically the normal way we initialize a node

Comment: @TarickWelling I have given the sample input/output and the output I have got too, please go through my question.

Comment: @mystic It is an invalid construction. There is nothing normal.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ya, thank you, but that doesn't fix my error, please go through my code completely

Comment: As for which IDE to use for C, I'd probably go for Eclipse because there is a pre-packaged version with the C dev tools. My second choice might be VS Code. But really, almost all IDEs out there support C to some degree.

Comment: @Hulk thanks, but I meant something similar to pythontutor.com,

Comment: @TarickWelling hope the question is clear now?, let me know so that I can improve,I'm new to StackOverflow as well.

Comment: `SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtPosition(...) {...}`  SinglyLinkedListNode is not a type name. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @wildplasser SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtPosition(...) {...}, is a pointer to the function of type SinglyLinkedListNode, this is written in " C " language, hope it clears the confusion.

Comment: BTW: why do you allocate two nodes when you intend to insert only one?

Comment: @mystic well, it seems that site also supports C: http://www.pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit

Comment: @wildplasser, ya, but that doesn't solve the error, I would be glad if you help me out with mistake in that code.

Comment: Maybe there is more than one error?

Comment: @wildplasser I would like to know what the second error is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues and the code is actually much simpler.

You were doing `malloc` *twice* instead of only once, so you were leaking memory on each call.

Don't cast `malloc:`. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

`SinglyLinkedListNode` is a bit long. When used in a lot of places, this doesn't scale well. How about something shorter like `Node` or `SlNode`

---

Here's a refactored version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

Node *
insertNodeAtPosition(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    int i = 0;
    Node *prev;
    Node *pcurr;
    Node *pnew;

    pnew = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pnew->data = data;

    // find the correct place to insert
    prev = NULL;
    for (pcurr = head;  pcurr != NULL;  pcurr = pcurr->next, i += 1) {
        if (i >= position)
            break;
        prev = pcurr;
    }

    // link up the element that will follow the new node
    pnew->next = pcurr;

    // insert into middle or end of list
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = pnew;

    // insert into empty list or _before_ the first node
    else
        head = pnew;

    return head;
}

void
printlist(Node *head)
{
    Node *pcurr;

    printf("List:");

    for (pcurr = head;  pcurr != NULL;  pcurr = pcurr->next)
        printf(" %d",pcurr->data);

    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *fi;
    Node *head = NULL;
    int count;
    int newval;
    int pos;

    fi = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (fi == NULL) {
        perror("input.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fi," %d",&count);

    for (int i = 0;  i < count;  ++i) {
        fscanf(fi," %d",&newval);
        printf("new: %d\n",newval);
        head = insertNodeAtPosition(head,newval,count + 10);
    }
    printlist(head);

    while (1) {
        if (fscanf(fi," %d %d",&newval,&pos) != 2)
            break;
        printf("insert: %d at %d\n",newval,pos);
        head = insertNodeAtPosition(head,newval,pos);
    }
    printlist(head);

    fclose(fi);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the test file: `input.txt`:

```
3
16 13 7
1 2
9 0
8 0
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
new: 16
new: 13
new: 7
List: 16 13 7
insert: 1 at 2
insert: 9 at 0
insert: 8 at 0
List: 8 9 16 13 1 7
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> can you also tell me why we have to use a pointer `*prev`? why only `pcurr` and `pnew` are not sufficient? It would help me in learning this new concept being a beginner.

Sure. If we're inserting at the head of the list because the list is empty or we want to insert at the head (i.e. we want a new head even if we have other nodes in the list), we adjust `head`.

But, if we're inserting in the middle of the list or appending to the end of the list, we need to know what the previous node is.

Consider that we're trying to append to the end of the list. We need to know the existing/prior tail [last element] of the list. If we have:

```
head | node1 | node2 | node3
```

Then, `node3` is the tail of the list. `node3->next` will be `NULL`. To append, we create the new node (`pnew`) and we have to set `node3->next = pnew`, so we get:

```
head | node1 | node2 | node3 | pnew
                       prev
```

Here, `prev` will end up having the value of `node3`, so setting `prev->next = pnew` is just like setting `node3->next = pnew`. Note that when appending to the end, `pcurr` will be `NULL`.

We call it `prev` because it (the previous node) can also be *any* node that we wish to insert *after*, even if `prev` is in the middle of the list (e.g. `node2`). That would look like (*before* the insertion):

```
head | node1 | node2 | node3
               prev    pcurr
```

After the insertion, we want:

```
head | node1 | node2 | pnew | node3
               prev           pcurr
```

In this case, `pcurr` will be `node3` (i.e. `prev->next`).

So, `prev` points to the node just *prior* to where we want to insert `pnew` and `pcurr` points to the node just *after* where we want to insert `pnew`.

In other words, after insertion, `prev` is the node just to the left of `pnew` (i.e. the node that *precedes* it). `pcurr` is the node just to the right of `pnew` (i.e. the node that *follows* it). If `pcurr` is null, there is *no* following node, but setting `pnew->next = pcurr` works in *all* cases, *regardless* of the values of `head` or `prev` being null or not.

If `prev` ends up being `NULL`, this means that the list is either empty or we wish to insert `pnew` at the head/front of the list. In that case, we can't try to dereference [a null] `prev`, so we just set `head` to `pnew`. Then, we're returning an *updated* `head` pointer.

There are several possible list states and insertion operations:

1. list is empty (adjust the head)
2. we want to insert the new node *before* the head of the [non-empty] list (adjust the head)
3. we want to insert the new node somewhere in the middle of the list
4. we want to append the new node at the end of the list (adjust tail or head if tail is null)

I think it would be helpful for you to diagram each of these separate cases using pencil and paper. Then, verify, by hand, that the code handles each of these cases, even if the list has prior elements or is empty.

The important thing to note about the above code is that it uses variables that work for several different cases, using the same code path, minimizing the number of `if/else` clauses to handle the various edge cases in a *uniform* way.

The type of simplification I did occurs again and again when coding. Thoroughly understanding what was done and *why* will help you immeasurably in the future.

Any one function that one writes, by itself, may not seem like much. But, magnify this across hundreds or thousands of functions, and it will pay dividends far beyond the initial extra work.

A maxim: *As simple as it needs to be--and no simpler*

The simpler (i.e. the cleaner) the code, the more likely it is to be correct, complete, and the easier it is to check for correctness. Contrary to popular belief, I've also found that the simpler code also tends to be faster.

Comment: I got it, kudos to you! :)

Comment: can you also tell me why we have to use a pointer *prev? why only pcurr and pnew are not sufficient? It would help me in learning this new concept being a beginner.

Comment: sure I will do that, also  I have upvoted it, probably it's not showing because I'm a new user, It pops up a message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score, so I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct SinglyLinkedListNode 
  {
        int data;
        SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
  };

    SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data, int position) 
{
    int i = 0;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *temp1, *pcurr, *prev;
    temp1 = (SinglyLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    prev = (SinglyLinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    if(position == 0&&head!=NULL)
    {
        temp1->data = data;
        temp1->next = head;     //new node's next will point to head and new node will become the new head
        head = temp1;          //since the insertion is made at start, new node(temp1) will becomes the new head.
        return head;
    }
    else if(head == NULL)      //if linked list is empty
    {
        temp1->data = data;    
        temp1->next = NULL;
        head = temp1;         //just set the new node as head of linked list and return the head node
        return head; 
    }
    else
    {
        int i=0;         //for iterating to the required position
        temp->data = data;

        //store 2 nodes, one node which will store prev node and another to store current node. The temp node will go between these 
        prev = head,pcurr = head->next; 
        while(i != position-1 && pcurr != NULL){  //traverse the linked list till you reached the insertion position
            i++;
            prev = pcurr;
            pcurr = pcurr->next;
        }
        if(i != position-1){
            return head;     //can't insert at the specified position
        }
        prev->next = temp;   //point the node preceding the insertion position to new node to be inserted
        temp->next = pcurr; //point the new node to the next node to maintain the linked list
        return head;
    }  
}
```

I hope the above changes will solve your question. I have added comments wherever required to help you understand the code. Please comment if you find any error and I will correct it.

Comment: thank you so much, Your code has solved my problem, I would be glad if you let me know why I can't use a do-while loop, would be more helpful if you can tell my error in my code.Thanks again ;)

Comment: do-while would work as well with minor edits in my answer code.